# Why the dimension of numpy array np.array([(1,2,3,2,3,4)]) is 2?

Tags: numpy

```py
a = np.array([(1,2,3,2,3,4)])
print(a.ndim)
```

> Why the mentioned array is 2 dimensional and not 1?

Comment: You're creating an array from a list containing a tuple, this has a depth equal to two, the array dimension will be two.

Comment: What shape and dtype did you want?

Comment: `np.array` treats tuples like lists, at least for the default numeric dtypes.  For a compound (structured) dtype the input should be a list of tuples, but that's a more advanced topic.

Comment: @hpaulj I was just playing with np arrays for first time and got into this strange situation. Thanks anyways

Comment: When playing around it's a good idea to check the `shape` and `dtype`, and if the array isn't too big, display the whole thing.  In this case the shape should be `(1,6)`.

Comment: Yeah it was, but as I was new to numpy I missed it, but then I found one more thing that tuple needs an extra comma if it's a single element tuple. 
While handling with Dataframes I do check regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you passed a list containing a tuple so this becomes 2 dimensional, if you remove the list `[]` then it shows `ndim` as 1:

```
In[29]:
a = np.array((1,2,3,2,3,4))
a.ndim
Out[29]: 1
```

What you did was no different to:

```
In[30]:
a = np.array([[1,2,3,2,3,4]])
a.ndim
Out[20]: 2
```

Where we pass a list containing a list

When `numpy` calls the `__array__` method on your passed param, your passed arg returns a nested sequence and not a 1-D array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the datatype actually. I had one other doubt but then your answer helped me search in right direction. a = np.array([(1),(2),(3),(4)])
print(a.shape). I was getting 1 dimensional array again. I got to know that (1,) is a tuple not (1). Though I can't upvote your answer as I am a newbie.

Comment: Oh! Did that, It's good to be on the contributing side of this beautiful site but there are so many limitations